# Trying to return a static file in web.py but getting "not found" error message

Tags: pythonanywhere, web.py

I have a web.py server hosted on pythonanywhere.com doing some handy things with python.

Now I'd like to just serve a straightforward html file from the same server i.e. just return the contents of a static html file to the client

The comments/answers below state that it should be possible, out of the box, to serve static files in the `static` directory, located in the same directory as the main python file which contains the following :

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'hello'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, Joe'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The server above works fine, when I go to `http://myhost/` it displays "Hello , Joe".
The directory `static` exists and contains a file `small.jpg` but when I try the url `http://myhost/static/small.jpg` it gives me "not found"

Previous text of question up to Nov 9th 2022 is below :

original question title : Trying to return a html file in web.py but getting "No template named ....." error message

So I've looked at the web.py documentation on serving [static files](https://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles) and [templating](https://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#templating) and I think the following code should work :

```
import web
render = web.template.render('static/')
# have also tried render = web.template.render('/full/path/to/static/')
urls = (
    '/getlatlongEIRCODE', 'getlatlongEIRCODE', #other stuff
    '/getlatlongGOOGLE', 'getlatlongGOOGLE',    #other stuff
    '/getmonthlyPV', 'getmonthlyPV',   #other stuff
    '/Tomas', 'Tomas',
)

class Tomas:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Tomas()
```

I have created a folder `static` at the same level as my file above (which works fine for the other scripts) and i have created a file `Tomas.html` in the static folder containing

```
<h1>Help me</h1>
```

However I get an error message when I go to https://example.com/Tomas

```
<class 'AttributeError'> at /Tomas
No template named Tomas
```

P.S. From the [static files](https://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles) page it seems to say I should just be able to put the Tomas.html file in a folder called "static" and then access is via https://example.com/static/Tomas.html but that is not working (it returns "not found")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case of the disappearing /static/ directory was related to the fact that I'm hosting on pythonanywhere.com

Even though the web.py documentation says that the /static/ folder is plugged in by default, that's not the case in pythonanywhere and you need to expressly make the link between the url http://yourhost/static/ and /path/to/static in the Web part of the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative path to your template directory without paying attention to the working directory. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't improve anything, I've updated the code showing the full path in the web.template.render line

Comment: Ok. What is the output if you do "ls /full/path/to/static/"

Comment: ls /full/path/to/static/ gives me the three files in the static directory

`Timetable.html Tomas.html index1.html`

Answer (score 1):

You're working too hard. 'static' is built in.

As the documentation says, `http://localhost/static/logo.png` will return the file `logo.png` from the existing directory `static`, which is relative to your webserver root.

Do not use render() for this (not needed). Also, do not list your desired file ('/Tomas') in the urls list (not needed).

*Anything* under the `static` directory can be accessed with the url `https://localhost/static/...`

"static" is hardcoded in the web.py server, so you cannot (easily) change this to some other folder. The suggestion in the web.py documents is to have nginx or apache host your application and use an Alias *there* to go to web.py static. (I think you can also add StaticMiddleware to your web.py application, but you'd need to investigate that yourself -- look at web.application.run()

Comment: Man, I wish it was just built in. I've rewritten the question, stripping it back to doing exactly as you say, and I cannot serve even an image file from the static folder

Comment: Turns out the issue was the fact that i'm hosting on pythonanywhere. See my answer